# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'localLibrary' when trying to run a python script from R with reticulate

Tags: python, r, modulenotfounderror, reticulate

I am trying to execute a python script via R using the following lines of code:

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("pandas")

py_run_file("pathToPythonScript/Script.py")
```

The script starts running but then it crashes as it fails to import some useful scripts/functions from a local library called src_functions:

```
    from src_functions import config_Full_Version as config
    from src_functions import file_handler as fh
    from src_functions import plotting as plo
    from src_functions import benchmark_data
    from src_functions import modifications as mod
    ...
```

The error i get is the following:
**Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src_functions'**

The script works perfectly fine when executed directly in python.

One easy-win solutions could be to copy paste all the above codes into the main script thus avoiding sourcing the functions from other python scripts but, if possible, i would like to avoid this. Any alternative solution?